# Is it possible to alter the behaviour of Experience Manager Page Type Preview?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I am setting up some Page Types for use in creating new pages via Experience Manager (XPM). You can optionally specify a *Page Type Example URL* which shows a preview of how the page will look to help editors determine whether this is the right page type to create for their needs. It seems that this needs to be a full URL (including domain/protocol eg: `http://staging/en/news/article.html`).

Is it possible to somehow get this working with a url relative to the publication site root url (eg `/news/article.html`) or specify a (managed) link to the page (`tcm:12-123-64`) which would then result in the equivalent page on the *local* site you are creating the page in being previewed? This would enable my page types to not contain environment specific urls, give a different preview depending on blueprint context and also prevent issues if the page was moved (in the case we used a URI).

A second option that would work well for me is that the preview url defaults to the URL/URI of the Page Type page itself. I would publish all Page Types pages to staging only, and use these as the preview examples - this would be much more stable as Editors would not be able to move or unpublish these. I guess I could use the event system to auto-populate the *Page Type Example URL* (is this app data?), but again I would want this to be without the domain, or the URI of the page rather than a URL.

Comment: This may not answer your question (so I made it a comment), but I like to create screenshots of the page types, and use this as the example image. It gives more control and allows you to put some instructions in there as well.

Comment: I like that line of thinking... that would be environment independent and avoid issues with using 'real pages'. It would not be local site specific, but thats probably the least of my concerns.

Answer (score 4):

The URLs are evaluated in the XPM application, not on your staging website.

So any relative URL would be relative to the CME website. I suppose you could do handle the request and show the right preview, but that would be a custom solution. There is no support in the product for the kinds of features you mention -- the URL is loaded in an IFrame without any prior manipulation.